# Call a method every X seconds with different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

**FYI:** I know there are many "how can you call a method every X seconds using JavaScript" questions out there; this is slightly different so please don't mark as duplicate unless it truly is.

**Problem:** I have a method `move` that takes in a direction parameter (i.e. `r`,`l`,`u`,or `d`).  I want to call my `move` method every X seconds with one parameter, but I want it to "cancel" the current `move` interval that's running any other parameter.  For example, if I'm running `move('r')` every 1 second, and then I trigger the `move('d')` event to run every 1 second, I want to cancel the `move('r')` method.

**Code:**

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.which == RIGHT){
            window.setInterval(function(){
                //CANCEL OTHER CURRENT "MOVES" HERE
                move('r');
            }, 500);

        } else if (event.which == LEFT) {
            window.setInterval(function(){
                //CANCEL OTHER CURRENT "MOVES" HERE
                move('l');
            }, 500);
        } else if (event.which == UP){
            window.setInterval(function(){
                //CANCEL OTHER CURRENT "MOVES" HERE
                move('u');
            }, 500);
        } else if (event.which == DOWN){
            window.setInterval(function(){
                //CANCEL OTHER CURRENT "MOVES" HERE
                move('d');
            }, 500);
        }
    });
```

**Edit**
Thanks all for the awesome answers. A slight combination of a few answers below allowed me to finish up my project (well, almost) - http://jsfiddle.net/thomasmclaughlin/8c9ww/ - Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post your move() function here? And better you should just update a character with `r` `l` `d` `u` and pass that variable in the function with `setInterval`.

Comment: Are you coding Snake Xenzia? :P

Comment: @sabithpocker haha yes indeed. Almost there - http://jsfiddle.net/thomasmclaughlin/8c9ww/

Comment: I miss those days :( let me check if they have one in App Store :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a global timer variable setup for your interval

```
var myInterval = null;
```

Now have a method to set the interval, but first checking if one is in progress:

```
function startInterval(r, l, u, d) {
    if (myInterval != null) clearInterval(myInterval)

    myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        move(r, l, u, d);
    }, 500);
}
```

Now each time you call `startInterval`, it will cancel the current interval if there is one and start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be better. Update variable simply, and pass it in the function.

```
$x = '';

$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.which == RIGHT){
        $x = 'r';
    } else if (event.which == LEFT) {
        $x = 'l';
    } else if (event.which == UP){
        $x = 'u';
    } else if (event.which == DOWN){
        $x = 'd';
    }
});

window.setInterval(function(){
   move($x);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once consideration is to change your mathod of tracking the move.  I suggest keeping your "move" in one small array, x and y.  Set the current move by setting the x or why you wish to modify

```
'u'  move=[-500,0]
'd'  move=[500,0]
'l'  move=[0,-500]
'd'  move=[0,500]
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach to the movement - I'll definitely try to work this into my project

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd personally go about it is completely different, but here goes a pseudocode/real code mixture:

```
var key = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    //check the event.which here, and set them to 1-4 depending on the event.which
});
$(document).keyup(function() {
    key = 0;
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(move(key), 500);
});
```